# Inverter circuit (From new "operation")

Tags: boolean-algebra

If I have this truth table how can I make inverter circuit such that F(x)=~x

```
x   y   x⊡y
0   0   1
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

Example of other circuit:
[image]
I really don't have an idea. Thanks

Comment: Do you see that if you set one wire to zero, you have the function already?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yeah I saw that, however I didn't know that I'm allowed to do that. Thanks !!